# SpeechRecognition Error Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have installed speech recognition both on python3 and python on raspbian when I try to run my python file I get the following error

> (hhsmartmirror) pi@raspberrypi:~/AI-Smart-Mirror $ python bot.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bot.py", line 13, in
>   
>       from speech import Speech   File "/home/pi/AI-Smart-Mirror/speech.py", line 3, in 
>       import speech_recognition as sr ImportError: No module named speech_recognition

code files:

```
#bot.py
#speechrecognition, pyaudio, brew install portaudio
import sys
sys.path.append("./")

import requests
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import json
import traceback
from nlg import NLG
from speech import Speech
from knowledge import Knowledge
from vision import Vision

my_name = "Aaron"
launch_phrase = "ok mirror"
use_launch_phrase = True
weather_api_token = "Bearer d1e49b263abd08d422822b72b4c3eec4"
wit_ai_token = "Bearer CL47LPKJWMNDNWPVMY4RPTZR3JDCZ2GZ"
debugger_enabled = True
camera = 0


class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nlg = NLG(user_name=my_name)
        self.speech = Speech(launch_phrase=launch_phrase, debugger_enabled=debugger_enabled)
        self.knowledge = Knowledge(weather_api_token)
        self.vision = Vision(camera=camera)

    def start(self):
        """
        Main loop. Waits for the launch phrase, then decides an action.
        :return:
        """
        while True:
            requests.get("http://localhost:8080/clear")
            if self.vision.recognize_face():
                print "Found face"
                if use_launch_phrase:
                    recognizer, audio = self.speech.listen_for_audio()
                    if self.speech.is_call_to_action(recognizer, audio):
                        self.__acknowledge_action()
                        self.decide_action()
                else:
                    self.decide_action()

    def decide_action(self):
        """
        Recursively decides an action based on the intent.
        :return:
        """
        recognizer, audio = self.speech.listen_for_audio()

        # received audio data, now we'll recognize it using Google Speech Recognition
        speech = self.speech.google_speech_recognition(recognizer, audio)

        if speech is not None:
            try:
                r = requests.get('https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160918&q=%s' % speech,
                                 headers={"Authorization": wit_ai_token})
                print r.text
                json_resp = json.loads(r.text)
                entities = None
                intent = None
                if 'entities' in json_resp and 'Intent' in json_resp['entities']:
                    entities = json_resp['entities']
                    intent = json_resp['entities']['Intent'][0]["value"]

                print intent
                if intent == 'greeting':
                    self.__text_action(self.nlg.greet())
                elif intent == 'snow white':
                    self.__text_action(self.nlg.snow_white())
                elif intent == 'weather':
                    self.__weather_action(entities)
                elif intent == 'news':
                    self.__news_action()
                elif intent == 'maps':
                    self.__maps_action(entities)
                elif intent == 'holidays':
                    self.__holidays_action()
                elif intent == 'appearance':
                    self.__appearance_action()
                elif intent == 'user status':
                    self.__user_status_action(entities)
                elif intent == 'user name':
                    self.__user_name_action()
                elif intent == 'personal status':
                    self.__personal_status_action()
                elif intent == 'joke':
                    self.__joke_action()
                elif intent == 'insult':
                    self.__insult_action()
                    return
                elif intent == 'appreciation':
                    self.__appreciation_action()
                    return
                else: # No recognized intent
                    self.__text_action("I'm sorry, I don't know about that yet.")
                    return

            except Exception as e:
                print "Failed wit!"
                print(e)
                traceback.print_exc()
                self.__text_action("I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what you meant by that")
                return

            self.decide_action()

    def __joke_action(self):
        joke = self.nlg.joke()

        if joke is not None:
            self.__text_action(joke)
        else:
            self.__text_action("I couldn't find any jokes")

    def __user_status_action(self, nlu_entities=None):
        attribute = None

        if (nlu_entities is not None) and ("Status_Type" in nlu_entities):
            attribute = nlu_entities['Status_Type'][0]['value']

        self.__text_action(self.nlg.user_status(attribute=attribute))

    def __user_name_action(self):
        if self.nlg.user_name is None:
            self.__text_action("I don't know your name. You can configure it in bot.py")

        self.__text_action(self.nlg.user_name)

    def __appearance_action(self):
        requests.get("http://localhost:8080/face")

    def __appreciation_action(self):
        self.__text_action(self.nlg.appreciation())

    def __acknowledge_action(self):
        self.__text_action(self.nlg.acknowledge())

    def __insult_action(self):
        self.__text_action(self.nlg.insult())

    def __personal_status_action(self):
        self.__text_action(self.nlg.personal_status())

    def __text_action(self, text=None):
        if text is not None:
            requests.get("http://localhost:8080/statement?text=%s" % text)
            self.speech.synthesize_text(text)

    def __news_action(self):
        headlines = self.knowledge.get_news()

        if headlines:
            requests.post("http://localhost:8080/news", data=json.dumps({"articles":headlines}))
            self.speech.synthesize_text(self.nlg.news("past"))
            interest = self.nlg.article_interest(headlines)
            if interest is not None:
                self.speech.synthesize_text(interest)
        else:
            self.__text_action("I had some trouble finding news for you")

    def __weather_action(self, nlu_entities=None):

        current_dtime = datetime.datetime.now()
        skip_weather = False # used if we decide that current weather is not important

        weather_obj = self.knowledge.find_weather()
        temperature = weather_obj['temperature']
        icon = weather_obj['icon']
        wind_speed = weather_obj['windSpeed']

        weather_speech = self.nlg.weather(temperature, current_dtime, "present")
        forecast_speech = None

        if nlu_entities is not None:
            if 'datetime' in nlu_entities:
                if 'grain' in nlu_entities['datetime'][0] and nlu_entities['datetime'][0]['grain'] == 'day':
                    dtime_str = nlu_entities['datetime'][0]['value'] # 2016-09-26T00:00:00.000-07:00
                    dtime = dateutil.parser.parse(dtime_str)
                    if current_dtime.date() == dtime.date(): # hourly weather
                        forecast_obj = {'forecast_type': 'hourly', 'forecast': weather_obj['daily_forecast']}
                        forecast_speech = self.nlg.forecast(forecast_obj)
                    elif current_dtime.date() < dtime.date(): # sometime in the future ... get the weekly forecast/ handle specific days
                        forecast_obj = {'forecast_type': 'daily', 'forecast': weather_obj['weekly_forecast']}
                        forecast_speech = self.nlg.forecast(forecast_obj)
                        skip_weather = True
            if 'Weather_Type' in nlu_entities:
                weather_type = nlu_entities['Weather_Type'][0]['value']
                print weather_type
                if weather_type == "current":
                    forecast_obj = {'forecast_type': 'current', 'forecast': weather_obj['current_forecast']}
                    forecast_speech = self.nlg.forecast(forecast_obj)
                elif weather_type == 'today':
                    forecast_obj = {'forecast_type': 'hourly', 'forecast': weather_obj['daily_forecast']}
                    forecast_speech = self.nlg.forecast(forecast_obj)
                elif weather_type == 'tomorrow' or weather_type == '3 day' or weather_type == '7 day':
                    forecast_obj = {'forecast_type': 'daily', 'forecast': weather_obj['weekly_forecast']}
                    forecast_speech = self.nlg.forecast(forecast_obj)
                    skip_weather = True


        weather_data = {"temperature": temperature, "icon": icon, 'windSpeed': wind_speed, "hour": datetime.datetime.now().hour}
        requests.post("http://localhost:8080/weather", data=json.dumps(weather_data))

        if not skip_weather:
            self.speech.synthesize_text(weather_speech)

        if forecast_speech is not None:
            self.speech.synthesize_text(forecast_speech)

    def __maps_action(self, nlu_entities=None):

        location = None
        map_type = None
        if nlu_entities is not None:
            if 'location' in nlu_entities:
                location = nlu_entities['location'][0]["value"]
            if "Map_Type" in nlu_entities:
                map_type = nlu_entities['Map_Type'][0]["value"]

        if location is not None:
            maps_url = self.knowledge.get_map_url(location, map_type)
            maps_action = "Sure. Here's a map of %s." % location
            body = {'url': maps_url}
            requests.post("http://localhost:8080/image", data=json.dumps(body))
            self.speech.synthesize_text(maps_action)
        else:
            self.__text_action("I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what location you wanted.")

    def __holidays_action(self):
        holidays = self.knowledge.get_holidays()
        next_holiday = self.__find_next_holiday(holidays)
        requests.post("http://localhost:8080/holidays", json.dumps({"holiday": next_holiday}))
        self.speech.synthesize_text(self.nlg.holiday(next_holiday['localName']))

    def __find_next_holiday(self, holidays):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        for holiday in holidays:
            date = holiday['date']
            if (date['day'] > today.day) and (date['month'] > today.month):
                return holiday

        # next year
        return holidays[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = Bot()
    bot.start()












# speech.py
# speechrecognition, pyaudio, brew install portaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import requests
from gtts import gTTS
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


class Speech(object):
    def __init__(self, launch_phrase="mirror mirror", debugger_enabled=False):
        self.launch_phrase = launch_phrase
        self.debugger_enabled = debugger_enabled
        self.__debugger_microphone(enable=False)

    def google_speech_recognition(self, recognizer, audio):
        speech = None
        try:
            speech = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + speech)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

        return speech

    def listen_for_audio(self):
        # obtain audio from the microphone
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        m = sr.Microphone()
        with m as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            self.__debugger_microphone(enable=True)
            print "I'm listening"
            audio = r.listen(source)

        self.__debugger_microphone(enable=False)
        print "Found audio"
        return r, audio

    def is_call_to_action(self, recognizer, audio):
        speech = self.google_speech_recognition(recognizer, audio)

        if speech is not None and self.launch_phrase in speech.lower():
            return True

        return False

    def synthesize_text(self, text):
        tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
        tts.save("tmp.mp3")
        song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("tmp.mp3")
        play(song)
        os.remove("tmp.mp3")

    def __debugger_microphone(self, enable=True):
        if self.debugger_enabled:
            try:
                r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/microphone?enabled=%s" % str(enable))
                if r.status_code != 200:
                    print("Used wrong endpoint for microphone debugging")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with the installed module. Did you install it using pip?

Comment: your `PYTHONPATH` for `portaudio` if already installed?

Comment: portaudio16 and pip already installed

Answer (score 0):

If you read back through the Traceback error, essentially it's saying that on line 13, you successfully imported Speech from speech, but inside of that file it is trying to import a module called speech_recognition.  Apparently, for reasons that I don't know, it cannot find that file.

**Some Potential Fixes**

- Try reinstalling the module
- Try reinstalling python on those devices
- Try doing it on a different device
- Try contacting the author of the module

Somebody else may be able to give some better advice as to fixes, seeing as I've never used this kind of module before, but this is my best bet.

Sorry for not being able to help more! Happy coding.